# https .mp3 link works fine with tablet(11+ api) not in 2.3 and below version

Tags: android, iphone, ssl, https, mp3

i have a problem with playing .mp3 link which is https, works fine in all tablet but not in phone (2.3 and below version.), is any thing extra that required to play hhtps link work on phone ?. when i run first time in phone it gives me an SSL exception,but after solving that error ,still have the problem https link.
While same https link works perfectly in iPhone.
What should it required to play on android phone ?

Answer (score 0):

i found that android doesn't support https live streaming below android 3.1, it only support after 3.1.

> Note: HTTPS is not supported before Android 3.1.

Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)